# Validating Login from checking sql table

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to check username and password by using a For Each Statement. If it validates then messagebox saying welcome appears, if it doesn't a message box saying "incorrect" will keep popping up over and over until it's done looping through the table. How can i correct this and just make it display one time. Also when it does validate a new window will show up with users First and Last name in a textbox, How can I edit users info and then save to db. Thanks for any help.

```
       Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim data As New datalinq1DataContext

    For Each row In data.Users
        If Not row.username = TextBox1.Text And Not row.password = TextBox2.Text Then
              Messagebox.Show("Incorrect")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + row.fname + " " + row.lname)
            Dim window As New Window1
            window.TextBox1.Text = row.fname
            window.TextBox2.Text = row.lname
            window.TextBox3.Text = row.username

            window.Show()
            Exit For
        End If

    Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an EXIT FOR after the msg box, but why are there multiple records being checked in the user table.   You should filter the user table to just the username entered.

Comment: I've tried an Exit for, it never helped. Can u give me an example of what you mean about filtering. I'm new to working with db's and tables. Thanks :)

Comment: how would it check the password if it's right or not if were to just check the username?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with VB and linq but try something like:
`For Each row In data.Users Where username = TextBox1.Text`
Then check each row for the password (if you might have multiple rows for the same sure for some reason).
If not I would just add the password to the where clause

Comment: Yea see thats what I originally tried doing. For some reason it won't let me do a "Where" after data.Users. Not sure why

Comment: Check out this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737944
EDIT:(pressed enter too fast) it seems to be closer to what you're tyring to do. `Dim q = From c In db.Customers Where c.City = "London"`

Answer (score 0):

Looping over each and every user in the table will give you performance issues in no time.

Instead of using a foreach, try figuring out why you can't access the proper LINQ extension methods. Have you references **System.Linq** and **System.Data.Linq**?

The proper way of checking for a user with corresponding username and password would be:

```
var potentialUser = data.Users
                          .SingleOrDefault(user => 
                              user.Username == userName && 
                              user.Password = passWord
                          ); 

if(potentialUser != null)
    Messagebox.Show("Welcome")
else 
    Messagebox.Show("Incorrect")
```